# Difference in SQL Between operator and ">=" & "<=" operator

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

We are using a SQL query to search on the basis of dateFrom and dateTo fields. for that i am using "**greater than equal to(>=)**" and "**less than equal to(<=)**" operator to search on the date fields. somewhere i also find that we can also use SQL "**Between**" operator to do the same. just wanted to confirm that is there any difference when we use "**Between**" operator and when we used "**(>= & <=)**" operator.

Comment: Which database vendor are you using? It makes a difference.

Comment: @j.w.r i am using MYSQL for the development and for the production it is Oracle.

Comment: Informix, DB2, PostreSQL, MySQL, Sqlite, MS Sql Server, Oracle ... are all inclusive, but I could swear there was one that wasn't at one point. So, as the others have noted, you should be fine. :)

Comment: @Mahendra, I'm curious for personal reasons: how does this development process work for you? Do you omit any vendor-specific functionality, including built-in functions, stored procedures, etc?

Comment: @j.w.r "I could swear there was one that wasn't at one point" -- if so, it would have been contrary to the SQL-92 Standard.

Comment: @Lukas we will not omit any function or procedure.

Comment: @onedaywhen -- Yep, my faulty memory! Actually, I now remember where I saw a warning once about `BETWEEN` behavior [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp). Weird

Comment: @j.w.r funny they just say "some databases, some other databases" instead of actually doing the work of a reliable source and checking it. I guess this is another one for http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern databases ship with very intelligent query execution optimisers. One of their main features is query transformation. *Logically equivalent* expressions can usually be transformed into each other. e.g. as Anthony suggested, the `BETWEEN` operator can be rewritten by Oracle (and MySQL) as two `AND`-connected comparisons, and vice versa, if `BETWEEN` isn't just implemented as syntactic sugar.

So even if there would be a difference (in performance), you can be assured that Oracle will very likely choose the better option.

This means that you can freely choose your preference, e.g. because of readability.

Note: it is not always obvious, what's logically equivalent. Query transformation rules become more complex when it comes to transforming `EXISTS`, `IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN`... But in this case, they are. For more details read the specification (chapter 8.3 between predicate):

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.

```
(x BETWEEN y AND z)
```

is the same as writing

```
((x >= y) AND (x <= z))
```

Answer (score 3):

No as such there is no difference(When using ORACLE) but using BETWEEN operator is more elegant way of comparing values for a range.